# Display the sum of a column when a criteria is met in another column

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table below:

```
 id |                       market                       |  process   | lines | items 
----+----------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+-------
  1 | Spain                                              | Pick       |    25 |   100
  2 | Spain                                              | Pick       |    50 |   100
  3 | UK                                                 | Pick       |   100 |   100
  4 | USA                                                | Pick       |    75 |    90
  5 | Metz                                               | Pick       |    10 |    20
  6 | UK                                                 | Pick       |    76 |    90
  7 | ROW                                                | Pick       |   200 |   300
  8 | Russia                                             | Pick       |   150 |  1000
  9 | South Africa                                       | Pick       |    35 |    50
 10 | Uk                                                 | Pick       |    15 |    20
 11 | USA                                                | Pick       |   123 |   123
 12 | Spain                                              | Pack       |    25 |    25
 13 | Spain                                              | Pack       |    50 |   100
 14 | UK                                                 | Pack       |   100 |   100
 15 | USA                                                | Pack       |    75 |    90
 16 | Metz                                               | Pack       |    10 |    20
 17 | UK                                                 | Pack       |    76 |    90
 18 | ROW                                                | Pack       |   200 |   300
 19 | Russia                                             | Pack       |   150 |  1000
 20 | South Africa                                       | Pack       |    35 |    50
 21 | Uk                                                 | Pack       |    15 |    20
 22 | USA                                                | Pack       |   123 |   123
```

What I need is to get the sum of the lines column when the process says "Pack" and then display the sum in a table on a HTML page using PHP.
I have verified the `SELECT SUM(lines) FROM jobs WHERE process='Pick';` code through the terminal and that works so I have placed it into a `pg_query`.
But I cannot get the sum to display on the page.

I have doctored a code I have already got which shows all the data which meets the criteria, but I cannot get it to work. The code is below:

```
<?php 
    $db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=vcbv2 user=postgres");
    $result2 = pg_query($db, "SELECT SUM(lines) FROM jobs WHERE process='Pick'");
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><td>PICK LINES TO DO</td></tr>\n";
    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        echo"<tr><td>{$row['$result2']}</tr>\n";
    }
    echo"</table>";
?>
```

Comment: what is `{$row['$result2']}` used for? did you copy the code somewhere?

Comment: you're using the variable `{$row['$result2']}` instead of the column name here. I.e.: `{$row['lines']}`

Comment: `SELECT SUM(lines) AS my_field` .... `$row['my_field']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some minor changes need to be done for your code

```
<?php 
  $db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=vcbv2 user=postgres");
  $result2 = pg_query($db, "SELECT SUM(lines) as total FROM jobs WHERE process='Pick'");
  echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr><td>PICK LINES TO DO</td></tr>\n";
            while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result2))
              {
              echo"<tr><td>{$row['total']}</tr>\n";
              }
       echo"</table>";
?>
```

this should fix the issue. here you are already adding column based on where condition in your query.